# When adding LinearLayout to ConstraintLayout, TextViews disappear

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, textview

I made a LinearLayout template xml, it has an ImageView and 2 TextViews in it, and I am trying to add it to my ConstraintLayout programatically. If I add it to a LinearLayout:

```
val layout: LinearLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutBlockSequence)

val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
val linearLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linearlayout_block, null, false) as LinearLayout
linearLayout.id = View.generateViewId()

layout.addView(linearLayout)
```

It works fine:

[image]

But when I add it to my ConstraintLayout:

```
val constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayoutBlockSequence)

val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
val linearLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linearlayout_block, null, false) as LinearLayout
linearLayout.id = View.generateViewId()

constraintLayout.addView(linearLayout)

val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)
constraintSet.connect(linearLayout.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.linearLayoutBlockSequence, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0)
constraintSet.connect(linearLayout.id, ConstraintSet.END, R.id.constraintLayoutBlockSequence, ConstraintSet.END, 0)
constraintSet.connect(linearLayout.id, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.constraintLayoutBlockSequence, ConstraintSet.START, 0)

constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
```

The TextViews are not there anymore:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `constraintSet.connect(linearLayout.id, ConstraintSet.END, R.id.constraintLayoutBlockSequence, ConstraintSet.END, 0)` just asking, but shouldn't this be `R.id.linearLayoutBlockSequence` instead of `constraintLayoutBlockSequence` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the ConstraintLayout's and LinearLayout's width set to wrap content? Maybe the problem is that the ConstraintLayout doesn't see the TextViews when it's created. Try adding this code after adding all elements to the ConstraintLayout:

```
constraintLayout.requestLayout()
```

This should force the layout to be redrawn, now including the width of the TextViews that are inside it.